# Detox build error: More than one file was found with OS independent path 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so'

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradlew, detox

I’m trying to build Detox tests for ReactNative project for android and it’s throwing this error

```
> Task :react-native pdf:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebugAndroidTest FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-pdf:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebugAndroidTest'.
> More than one file was found with OS independent path 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so'
```

After doing some research adding this block of code in app/build.gradle should’ve helped

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
    pickFirst '/libjsc.so'
    pickFirst '/libc++_shared.so'
    }
}
```

However for some reason, gradlew assembleAndroidTest is not using the packagingOptions to run its build which then results in More than one file was found with OS independent path 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so error.

Anyone knows a workaround for this?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I have since moved on from the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
More than one file was found with OS independent path 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so'
```

generally means ...that `lib/x86/libc++_shared.so` indeed exists twice (or more often) in the project. This can eg. be, when building from source and also having files in the `jniLibs` directory.